# Необходима ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Необходима ли запятая в данном предложении: "Эх, досада(,) придется слушать все"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом предложении всё зависит от того, чем считать слово *"досада"*. С одной стороны, оно выражает эмоциональную окраску, следовательно, может быть вводным, а с другой стороны, слово "досада" может быть сказуемым, тогда предложение становится бессоюзным, и можно поставить как запятую, так и тире. Но я склоняюсь к тому, что здесь пример вводного слова, поэтому поставил бы запятую.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, возможно также двоеточие, так как вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения поясняет первую.